# hidden form fields unset after some time

Tags: html, forms, field, hidden, isset

I have an `HTML` form with some hidden fields:

```
<form id="syncr" name="syncr_form" action="/index.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="sync">
</form>
```

The form is submitted through `javascript`:

```
function syncronize() {
    document.getElementById("syncr").submit();
}
```

I've noticed very strange behavior of this form - if the user submits the form short time (within a few minutes) after the page loaded it works fine. If the user clicks "submit" button long time (>10 minutes or so) after the page loaded the hidden field "form_id" is not set. I may set it in the submitting `javascript` but I hope there should be a better solution. Sessions are not used here.

Comment: This should not happen. Perhaps it is a session issue on the server.

Comment: Do you have full code? There is no way that wouldn't post unless there is a session timeout or something else that is un-setting that field's value